# How to create a calculated column in a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I really need a calculated column on a table with simple sum.

Please see below:

```
SELECT   key3
         ,SUM(UTOTALWBUD)
FROM     CONTACT1
         INNER JOIN CONTACT2
            ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE    KEY1 = 'Client'
GROUP BY KEY3
```

I have tried to create a calculated column by adding following

```
ALTER TABLE ManagerTaLog
ADD         WeeklyBudget as (   SELECT
                                        key3
                                        ,SUM(UTOTALWBUD)
                            FROM        CONTACT1
                                        JOIN CONTACT2
                                            ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
                            WHERE       KEY1 = 'Client'
                            GROUP BY    KEY3)
```

I got the error message:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Please advise what can I do about it.

Many thanks

### Part 2

I have create a function; however, i get null values please advise.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SumIt](@Key3 varchar)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT      SUM(UTOTALWBUD)
FROM        CONTACT1
            JOIN CONTACT2
                ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
            JOIN Phone_List
                ON CONTACT1.KEY3 = Phone_List.[Manager ]
WHERE       KEY1 = 'Client'
            AND Phone_List.[Manager ] = @Key3
GROUP BY [Manager ]

)
END

GO
```

Just select statment that returns values I wish to add to Phone_list table

```
SELECT      [Manager ]
            ,SUM(UTOTALWBUD)
FROM        CONTACT1
            JOIN CONTACT2
                ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
            JOIN Phone_List
                ON CONTACT1.KEY3 = Phone_List.[Manager ]
WHERE       KEY1 = 'Client'
GROUP BY    [Manager ]
```

### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CONTACT1](
    [ACCOUNTNO] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [COMPANY] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [CONTACT] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [LASTNAME] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TITLE] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [SECR] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PHONE1] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [PHONE2] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [PHONE3] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [FAX] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [EXT1] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [EXT2] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [EXT3] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [EXT4] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [ADDRESS1] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ADDRESS2] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ADDRESS3] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [CITY] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [STATE] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ZIP] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [COUNTRY] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DEAR] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [SOURCE] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KEY1] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KEY2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KEY3] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KEY4] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KEY5] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [STATUS] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [NOTES] [text] NULL,
    [MERGECODES] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CREATEBY] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [CREATEON] [datetime] NULL,
    [CREATEAT] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [OWNER] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [LASTUSER] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [LASTDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [LASTTIME] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [U_COMPANY] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [U_CONTACT] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [U_LASTNAME] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [U_CITY] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [U_STATE] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_COUNTRY] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_KEY1] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_KEY2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_KEY3] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_KEY4] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [U_KEY5] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [recid] [varchar](15) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phone_List](
    [Manager ] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SalesCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PayrollCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FName] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [idd] [tinyint] NULL,
    [OD] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [WeeklyBudget]  AS ([dbo].[SumIt]([manager]))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Your subquery returns **two values** - how is this going to be stored in a single computed column?!?!?!?

Comment: Show us the table definition. Are you certain that Key3 has a value?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but you call the function with `([dbo].[SumIt]([manager]))` instead of `([dbo].[SumIt]([manager ]))`  (note the extra space).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap your query into the function like this (it **HAS** to return one value):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SumIt(@Key1 varchar(max))
returns float
as
begin
  return (select sum(UTOTALWBUD) from
   CONTACT1 inner join
   CONTACT2 on
   CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO=CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
   where KEY1=@key1
   group by KEY3)
END
```

And use this function instead with calc field - something like this:

```
alter table ManagerTaLog add WeeklyBudget as dbo.SumIt(Key1)
```

**NOTE**

that it will be the performance killer for queries like that:

```
select * from ManagerTaLog
```

You should change your function in such a way, that is accept **NOT** `varchar` value, but `NVARCHAR(255)` - the same type as Manager column. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you resolve the issue of returning two values, one solution would be to implement the calculation in a function and use this function for the calculated column.

Some considerations

- I have assumed that it is `Key3` that needs to be passed to the function and have added a where clause to return the weekly budget for the given `Key3` value.
- The function will get executed for **every** record in a resultset where you add the calculated column.

**Script**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ManagerTaLogWeeklyBudget(@Key3 INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS 
BEGIN
  select sum(UTOTALWBUD) from
  CONTACT1 inner join
  CONTACT2 on
  CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO=CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
  where KEY1='Client'
        AND KEY3 = @Key3
  group by KEY3)

END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.ManagerTaLog
ADD WeeklyBudget AS dbo.fn_ManagerTaLogWeeklyBudget(Key3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have created function and altered table; however, result gives me null values

Comment: @user995506 - What about the comment I posted on your question 20 hours ago?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a subquery that returns **multiple values** to be used as the computed column expression.

You can have an expression that returns a **single value** - or you can wrap your code in a stored function - or you can create a view (with a JOIN or subquery) that combines this logic into something you can use

Answer (score 1):

IMHO It is a wrong way. You have to use trigger on CONTACT tables and update WeeklyBudget in these triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have calculated columns in a table but that will be present (and calculated) in all rows of the table.
The thing what you're trying to do in your select is called "**aggregate**". Try this:

```
select key3, sum(UTOTALWBUD) as WeeklyBudget from
CONTACT1 inner join CONTACT2 on CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO=CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
where KEY1='Client' 
group by key3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SumIt](@Key3 varchar)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT      SUM(ISNULL(UTOTALWBUD,0))
FROM        CONTACT1
            JOIN CONTACT2
                ON CONTACT1.ACCOUNTNO = CONTACT2.ACCOUNTNO
            JOIN Phone_List
                ON CONTACT1.KEY3 = Phone_List.[Manager ]
WHERE       KEY1 = 'Client'
            AND Phone_List.[Manager ] = @Key3
GROUP BY [Manager ]

)
END

GO
```

Hope this will help. Please note that this is not a proper solution, but this may help your particular scenario. Since the function is returning multiple values, you can either user a table valued function or just modify the query in a way that it will return only one value. But if the column is nullable please don't forget to add ISNULL.