# SQL Persisted Computed Column with Subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables

Table 1: **Items**

```
ItemID | DaysLastSold
```

Table2: **Listings**

```
ItemID | ListingID
```

Table3: **Sales**

```
ListingID | DateItemClosed
```

I got this query to work:

```
SELECT min(DATEDIFF(day, DateItemClosed, getdate())) as DaysLastSold 
    from Sales 
    where QtySold > 0 
        and ListingID in (SELECT ListingID from Listings where ItemID = 8101 )
```

What I'm trying to do is basically place this query into the DaysLastSold Column in the Items table. So when ever the column is selected it recalculates DaysLastSold using the ItemID in the neighboring column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a calculated column in a SQL Server 2008 table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725629/how-to-create-a-calculated-column-in-a-sql-server-2008-table)

Comment: You can't do this as a persisted computed column per the title. You can create a non persisted computed column by wrapping the query in a scalar UDF but this will fail if you try and mark it as persisted. Even as a non persisted column this would likely be a bad idea for performance reasons and much better inline in the queries that need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist that information you *could* create an indexed view that is made up of your calculated value and an ItemID.  Obviously this would not be a column in your original table though. You could then join in on this view when you need the information.

Personally I would probably just do it inline when you need it.  If you are concerned about performance, post the execution plan here and we may be able to make some suggestions.