# VB.NET BindingSource filter for Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

In MSSQL I can filter a query on a phone number like this:

```
where replace(phone,'-','') Like '%480555%'
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this on a Datasource. A normal query looks like this:

```
Dim stringFilter As String = String.Empty
String.Format("phone Like '%480555%'")
ViewCustomersBindingSource.Filter = stringFilter
```

However, this will not find any results because the datasource has the values with hyphens in it. REPLACE is not a valid argument for filtering.

My initial thought was to update the MSSQL View to strip the hyphens. However, for display, I would want to display the hyphens. I can not assume they will all look the same as some phone numbers might be a different country than the US.

Is there another way to filter on a telephone number and ignore the hyphens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can directly set a filter that ignores the hyphens (as in your first query) on your `binding source`. There is no String operations possible in the filter expression column. From this http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx the only string operation allowed is `+`.

But you can keep and display the original column which contains the hyphens, and add another column (without the hyphens) that you do not display, but that you use just for filtering.

With **MSSQL**, you can for example add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that uses the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx.) function.

Here is somes links that could help you to create a computed column:

- [How to replace double quotes in derived column transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210744/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-derived-column-transformation).
- [How to create a calculated column in a SQL Server 2008 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725629/how-to-create-a-calculated-column-in-a-sql-server-2008-table)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great idea. I added this to my view and voila. Thanks for the nudge.           `code`select id, companyname, phone, replace(phone,'-','') as phonesearch from customers

Comment: Glad i could help. I was first thinking to an expression column in datatable, but it is not possible due to limits of filter expression. And happy to learn about the MSSQL Replace function ;-)